# Java Swing actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

Hi there I'm working in a project where I had to create a CUI game and now convert it to GUI, I'm in the process of adding functionality to buttons that interact with the game but am having trouble.

This is the method I'm attempting to access. It's in a class called Pet.

```
public double feedPet() {

    if(this.hunger < MAX_HUNGER) {
        this.hunger += food;
            if(this.hunger > MAX_HUNGER) {
                this.hunger = MAX_HUNGER;
            }
        System.out.println(this.petName + " enjoyed the meal!");
        System.out.println("Hunger increased by " + food + " to a total of " + this.hunger);
        spacing();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(this.petName + " is currently full!");
        spacing();
    }

    return this.hunger;
}
```

This is the class that is trying to access the method.

```
public GamePanel(PetWorld petWorld, Pet pet, Game game) {
    initComponents();
    genComponents(pet);
}

private void genComponents(final Pet pet) {


    this.setSize(600, 600);

    graphicsPanel.setSize(600, 400);
    graphicsPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

    buttonPanel.setSize(600, 200);

    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Pet Options"));

    JButton feedBtn = new JButton("Feed");
    JButton playBtn = new JButton("Play");
    JButton sickBtn = new JButton("Medicine");
    JButton trainBtn = new JButton("Train");
    JButton sleepBtn = new JButton("Sleep");

    //// error occurring here I believe \\\\
    feedBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pet.feedPet();
        }
    });

    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //// Pet Options \\\\
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(feedBtn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(playBtn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(sickBtn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(trainBtn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 4;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(sleepBtn, gc);
```

}

I've had to make the pet final, I believe this to be bad as I alter values in the pet itself, eg happiness, hunger etc

The error which I am getting upon pressing the button

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pdcmainGUI.GamePanel$1.actionPerformed(GamePanel.java:63)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Is there a better way to implement what I'm trying to do? I'm guessing this is caused by the method trying to alter variable values but being set to final in the gui class?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious that `pet` is `null`, the question is why, but there's not enough context be 100% sure. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: you should provide the code of the class that instantiates `GamePanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to do with your declaration of the action listener. While you are creating the ActionListener() inside the genComponents(final Pet pet) procedure, this is not where it executes at runtime.

But first, lets also clear up the calling of a variable as **final**.  What this means is the `pet` cannot be reassigned to a different *pet*, it doesn't mean that you can't access methods of your `pet` that may change, such as isHungry(), setFed(boolean) etc.

Second, getting your `pet` into scope. When you *define* the `genComponents(final Pet pet)` procedure, the `pet` is in scope so the java compiler has no problem at compile time.  But at runtime the `genComponents(final Pet pet)` procedure gets executed, with the `pet` known, and during this execution it creates the `ActionListener`, which points to the variable location for the parameter.  At the completion of the `genComponents(...)` procedure the parameter goes out of scope.  When the `ActionListener` is triggered by pressing the button, it tries to refer to the memory location of the out-of-scope variable.

```
private void genComponents(final Pet pet) {

    ....

    feedBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pet.feedPet();   <-- pet refers to the parameter, but it is out of scope when this gets executed.
        }
    });

    ....
}
```

Solution space: To solve this problem the `pet` needs to be accessed from somewhere in scope, and you can do this by simply storing the `pet` as a private class variable.

```
public class GamePanel {

    private final Pet pet;

    public GamePanel(PetWorld petWorld, Pet pet, Game game) {
        this.pet = pet;
        initComponents();
        genComponents(); <-- remove the pet parameter
    }

    private void genComponents() {
        ....

        feedBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pet.feedPet();    <-- this pet now refers to the class variable, which is still in scope.
            }
        });

        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can't believe I had final confused like that. I've decided to restart my project and make it much clearer problems have arisen from trying to reuse my old game. Ill take on your advice, again thanks!